# Al redimensionar el tamaño del navegador, el div se "jala"

Tags: html, css

```css
.portada{
  border: 1px solid #e4e6eb;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: relative;

 

}

.img-portada{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
   
}
 

.img-perfil{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 300px;
    
}
```

```html
        <div class="portada">

             <img src="../img/p.jpg" alt="">
         
          <div class="img-perfil">

          </div>
        </div>
```

Necesito posicionar esa caja para hacer el clon de facebook y colocar la imagen de perfil. La verdad, sí la posiciono en su lugar, mi problema es que cuando estiro el navegador la `div` se jala: el resultado que quiero es que la `div` quede fija como facebook.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y bueno, este sería el código que estoy utilizando

```css
/*-------------------------PORTADA--------*/


.portada{
  border: 1px solid #e4e6eb;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: relative;

 

}

.img-portada{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
   
}
 

.img-perfil{
    border: 1px solid ;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 300px;
    
}
```

```html
        <div class="portada">

        <img src="../img/p.jpg" alt="">
         
          <div class="img-perfil">

          </div>

       
         
        


        </div>
```

Comment: No hay suficiente código para un [mre], incluso el ejemplo solo es una caja vacia.

Comment: Buenos días. Una disculpa aun no entiendo muy bien como funciona el foro, pero ya actualicé el código. La problemática es que mi esfera se mueve cuando dimensiono mi navegador, y lo que quiero conseguir es que quede fijo como lo tiene facebook. gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Cual es la posicion que quieres darle al circulo entonces ?? centro ?

Comment: Si, mira, quiero que quede en el centro, pero que  cuando jale el navegador el circulo se quede siempre en el centro ya lo intenté colocando la esfera con position fixed  y no me ha dado resultado nada compañero.

Comment: Si  usted ejecuta el código  y hace la ventana mas pequeña el circulo pierde la posición o sea que se jala para donde se dimensiona el navegador y es lo que que quiero conseguir que  quede fijo en el medio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He editado el codigo, para no tener un div con image, pero si backgrounds, los cuales poder modificar.

Por lo que logro entender, esto se aproxima a lo que buscas hacer.

Puedes verlo a pantalla completa para comprobar.

```css
.portada {
  border: 1px solid #e4e6eb;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://loremflickr.com/1280/720/hawk");
  background-size: auto auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
}

.img-perfil {
  background-image: url("https://loremflickr.com/320/240/eagle");
  background-position: center center;
  border: 3px solid darkblue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="portada">
  <div class="img-perfil">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pensé en hacerlo así con un background sería más comodo, pero si ya le meto php para que cache la imagen y la muestre. ¿podria yo meter una salida de php como ruta en una url? por ejemplo mis salidas son archivos php para que muestre la foto en el div. no sé si me explique jaja

Comment: Desde php, se lo metes al style del div por ejemplo.

Comment: ah perfecto. Entonces, lo intentaré así de esa manera, una pregunta no quiero ser malagradecido o algo parecido por falta de información de como se  usa el foro pero no se como ayudarte por tu ayuda, de mi parte yo te doy las gracias por tu tiempo y la información que me brindaste, veo que hacen puntuaciones pero no sé como puntuarte

Comment: Si te falta información, te recomiendo leer [tour] y [ask]. Para votar y puntuar, estan las flechas upvote y downvote, ademas de aceptar la respuesta.